# When does optional (?) mean undefinable or nullable in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Is the optional notation (?) describe a type as being `any | undefined` or `any | null` or either? In the following, it seems it is for both but I could not find if this is officially the case:

```js
type MyType = {
  prop1?: string;
  prop2: string | null;
}

const something: MyType = { prop2: null };
something.prop1?.toString();
something.prop2?.toString();
```

Does optional really mean `any | null | undefined`? By `any` I mean generically any type.

Comment: Consider that `const something: MyType = { prop2: null, prop1:null };` doesn't work. `null` and `undefined` are fundamentally different (i.e. they are different types: `undefined` is `undefined` but `null` is an `object`). When you declare a prop as `prop1?: string`, `prop1` can have a value of `string | undefined`, but **not** `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` has multiple meanings in typescript (and in javascript for that matter). In a typescript type, `?` means the property might be undefined. `null` plays no role in this. The following line is an example of `?` in a type:

```
type MyType = {
  prop1?: string; // similar to prop1: string | undefined
}
```

In javascript code (and thus typescript code inherits this syntax), `?.` is the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). It's similar to accessing a property via `.`, except it will short circuit evaluation if the value is null or undefined. Note that this is never a `?` on its own, it's always combined with a `.`, and it's always in code not types.

The following is an example of `?.` in code:

```
something.prop1?.toString();
```

Comment: `prop1?: string; // similar to prop1: string | undefined` not really

Comment: Can you elaborate @Ahmed, I thought it was

Comment: `prop1?: string` means that the property prop1 may not exist in the type and if it does it should be of type `string`  so `const something: MyType = { prop2: null}`  is correct however `prop1: string | undefined` means that prop1 should exist and should be either of type `string` or `undefined` so `const something: MyType = { prop2: null}` will lead to this error : `Property 'prop1' is missing in type '{ prop2: null; }' but required in type 'MyType'`

Comment: Put another way: `prop1: string | undefined` requires an explicit undefined, `prop1?: string` allows an implicit undefined. Either way, the two possible values are `string` and `undefined`.